# Difference between 様子, 姿 and 格好

Tags: meaning, word-choice

These are complicated words (at least to me) and I'm aware that they have multiple meanings, but in the context of describing the appearance of someone/something how do 様子, 姿 and 格好 differ? To what extent are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic differences (of relevant meanings of those words) are:

- 様子 is modified by phrases saying about inner state. So it could be defined as an inner/mental state appearing outside.
- 姿 is an overall outward appearance
- 恰好 is also an outward appearance, but more specifically about clothes. It can refer to a shape as well.

By examples:

1. 心配そうな{〇様子, △姿, ×恰好} *look of being worried*
2. 心配している{△様子, 〇姿, ×恰好} *a figure who is worried*
3. みすぼらしい{×様子, 〇姿, 〇恰好} *shabby* implying poor clothes

△ for 心配している様子 is a bit exaggerating, but 心配している implies that it is a fact, not inferred. 様子 fits less naturally.

- 山の様子 *how the mountain is* - if it is rainy, about to erupt etc.
- 山の姿 *how the mountain looks* - the appearance of the actual mountain.
- (山の恰好 is an abbreviated form of 山向けの恰好, outfit for mountain climbing)

Cf. Relevant thesaurus entries.

- [姿](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/32/meaning/m1u/%E5%A7%BF/)
- [様子](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/13627/meaning/m1u/%E6%A7%98%E5%AD%90/)